# js-beautify: command not found in node.js

Tags: node.js

Why I am unable to run js-beautify? Even after I install it, it doesn't seem to work.

http://pastie.org/8022125

Comment: I an new to node.js Can someone care to give a reason before a down vote.

Comment: Perhaps people don't appreciate the pastie, it's okay to post logs like that directly into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the module locally, which means it's installed in `./node_modules`.

The CLI scripts will be installed in `./node_modules/.bin`, so you can run them like this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/js-beautify
```

However, for modules that install scripts, it's more common to install the module globally, which means it will be installed in a location where the script ends up in a directory that will (probably) be in your `$PATH`:

```
[sudo] npm install js-beautify -g
```